# QR Codes from a third party - what are the most scalable options

Tags: marketing-cloud, third-party, barcode, qr-code

Until recently we were using the BarcodeURL ampscript function to generate readable barcodes for a ticketed event. The business now want to switch to a QR code instead.

As Marketing Cloud does not have a native ampscript function for generating QR codes, I found a series of solutions, [listed here](https://sfmarketing.cloud/2022/03/22/generating-barcodes-and-qr-codes-in-salesforce-marketing-cloud/), and another on the [IdeaExchange](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdcpuUAB/native-qr-code-support-in-marketing-cloud).

I just wondered if anyone has any experience with the reliability of any of these options - it's important that these tickets are generated correctly, and we'd be using them for up to 200,000 event tickets across ~50 events. Are any of these options objectively better than the others?

Comment: I don't think anyone here can speak on behalf of any of the services referenced in the resources you are referring to. That said, you should be aware, that the URLs are not accessed at send-time, as they only hold references to the image of the QR code on the service. 
Hence the load will be more distributed than e.g. sending 300.000 emails in 5 minutes. They are only requested upon emails being opened (excluding some cases of a.o. Gmail prefetching images).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the DataMatrix barcodes generated from the AMPscript [barcodeURL](https://ampscript.guide/barcodeurl) function?  It's similar looking and can encode thousands of characters.

If you're just needing to encode a link, it may work for you.

```ampscript
%%[

set @URL = "https://sprignaturemoves.com/category/salesforce-marketing-cloud"
set @dataMatrixBarcodeImage = BarcodeURL(@URL, "DataMatrix", 200, 200)

]%%
<img src="%%=v(@dataMatrixBarcodeImage)=%%">
```

[image: DataMatrix barcode]